# Content Query Webpart - display blog articles less that 4 hours

Tags: content-search-web-part

We are using a Content Search to display blog posts - however, due to the server setup, it's limited to a crawl every four hours (this cannot currently be adjusted). So new articles will not display until a new crawl is completed.  As a temporary solution, we want to add a content search to pull any new posts.  Happy to set this up, but need guidance on the following:

- Display only most recent posts which have been published within 4 hours
- Nice to have: display the image from the post (like the Content Search web part)

Comment: Are you referring temporary solution with the content query or content search? Content search works on your search results, as per your Organization settings in your next incremental call you will get that post

Comment: We need a content search (the crawl is immediate) this should display last 3 posts - published within 4 hours. We have set up the webpart, just need advice on how to set a formula to display anything within 4 hours. After the 4 hours they should disappear. thanks